# Kotlin async function not run in parallel

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a kotlin function just as following, And I expected it can wrap a sync IO action into async.

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> runIOAsync(f:suspend () -> T): Deferred<T> = coroutineScope{
    async(Dispatchers.IO) {
       f()
    }
}
```

Then I have my code in the calling side like

```kotlin
 runBlocking {
            repeat(5) {
                runIOAsync {
                    println(it)
                    println(Thread.currentThread())
                    Thread.sleep(3000)
                    println("After sleep $it")
                }.await()
            }
        }
```

But the actual out put is

```
0
Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#2,5,main]
After sleep 0
1
Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#3,5,main]
After sleep 1
2
Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#4,5,main]
After sleep 2
3
Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#5,5,main]
After sleep 3
4
Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#6,5,main]
After sleep 4
```

Which seems all tasks from my function are executed serially. Any one can please help to give an explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's put aside `runIOAsync` for the moment.

You're using `await()` right after calling `async()`, which means that you're effectively waiting for the end of your async execution before executing the next one.

Instead, start all tasks first and then await all of them. For instance you can use [awaitAll](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/await-all.html):

```kotlin
runBlocking {
    List(5) {
        async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            println(it)
            println(Thread.currentThread())
            Thread.sleep(3000)
            println("After sleep $it")
        }
    }.awaitAll()
}
```

Also, the way you're encapsulating the scope in `runIOAsync` is wrong, you will be waiting for the end of the async execution even without calling `await()` (`coroutineScope` is a suspending function that waits for all its child coroutines before resuming).

Instead, use `coroutineScope` to define the boundary of your coroutines executions, and you don't even have to `await` them. Since you don't need to get values from this code, you can also use `launch` instead of `async` here:

```kotlin
coroutineScope {
    repeat(5) {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            println(it)
            println(Thread.currentThread())
            Thread.sleep(3000)
            println("After sleep $it")
        }
    }
}
```

Declaring a `suspend` function returning a `Deferred` should be a red flag, and is quite confusing from an API standpoint: if you suspend it means you wait, if you return `Deferred` it means you don't wait (you immediately return a handle to some running computation). A function that does both would be quite weird.

If what you want is to make suspending code from IO-bound code, you can use instead the existing [withContext](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) function:

```kotlin
// this suspends until the code inside is done
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // run some blocking IO code
}
```

However, note that this is independent from defining concurrent code. If you want to run multiple things concurrently, even with suspend functions, you'll need coroutine builders such as `async` or `launch` like in the above code.

Comment: If I change the code to 
```
runBlocking {
            listOf(1, 2,3,4,5).map {
                runIOAsync {
                    println(it)
                    println(Thread.currentThread())
                    Thread.sleep(3000)
                    println("After sleep $it")
                }
            }.awaitAll()
        }
```
still get the same output

Comment: @Chunsen you have another problem with your custom `runIOAsync` function, I edited my answer.

Comment: Ye, your code runs as my expectation exactly,  but how can I fix my code if I still want a helper function to wrap a sync task to async.

Comment: @Chunsen what are you trying to encapsulate here exactly? As you can see, the `coroutineScope` usage is independent from the async tasks themselves, so you cannot group them together. Do you simply want to convert IO-bound code to suspend function?

Comment: `Do you simply want to convert IO-bound code to suspend function? `. Ye , if there is a way.

Comment: I updated my answer with more info about this. Note that using `withContext(IO)` does exactly that, but it's independent from running multiple tasks asynchronously in parallel (for this you would still need coroutine builders like `async` or `launch`).